# Why Cura flattens first layer of round objects?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code

When i am creating g file with Cura, it always flattens the first layer of round edges touching the plate. Is problem Cura or is there any setting that i can solve this?

Thanks,
Veysel :)

[image: This is a sample]

Comment: I played around a bit with a sphere, and found two things. The obvious one is that both the top and the bottom will be a bit flat due to the finite thickness of each layer.  The other is that it appears that adding a thick raft with an under-compensated airgap setting may improve the bottom of your object.  You may want to experiment with different raft settings.

Comment: Another observation: If I slice a cube which is standing on either an edge or a corner, I get no "flattening" at all.   It's quite possible that you can print your cylinder as-is with little to no observable flattening of the final object.

Answer (score 4):

All models must be sliced horizontally into layers in order to be printed, and each layer is flat. That is simply the bottom layer. Since you are printing a cylinder, you could always rotate it by 90 degrees, and stand it on its end (before you slice it, naturally). You should always consider the best orientation for printing any model.

Also, if you print a cylinder on its side, the slicer will need to generate a lot of support structures to support the lower curved surfaces. By printing a cylinder on its end, no support should be required.

Comment: Thanks but it must be printed on the round edge.For example when i print a wrench I lay it on surface in Cura, then screw's bottom is flat. It must be round as top of it. I know that all slices will be rectangular. But the first slice is too large in width. It should be thinner rectangular.

Comment: You can reduce the layer height. That will make the bottom layer narrower, but it will still be flat.